# Math operations list in Torch

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, neural-network, torch

How can I get a list of all math operations of torch?

I have a list of string in a json file which specify the name of function per layer and I want to create the NN dynamically based on it. So I want to check if the string is correct (if it is the name of a method in torch) and if so, give the input to that method.

Comment: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#math-operations There is a list of math operations in the documentation

Comment: @DomDJ I know it. I meant that I want to get the list during runtime. something like `inspection.getmembers(class, inspect.isfunction)` that return a list of all functions of class, but it doesn't work well for torch. For example, tanh is one of function but this command doesn't return it.